# How to make a given matrix to be diagonally dominant in Maxima

Tags: matrix, maxima

(From a handout reference) In order for the Gauss-Seidel and Jacobi methods to converge, it is necessary to check if the coefficient matrix is **diagonally dominant**, that is, the diagonal element should have the largest value among all the elements in its column. **If it is not yet diagonally dominant, employ pivoting**. For a matrix to be diagonally dominant, the following conditions should hold: (This is also known as *convergence*)

```
//convergence 
abs(A[i][i]) > summation(abs(A[i][j]),j=1 to n) where j != i for all i...n
//swapping rows in a matrix for partial pivoting
A:rowswap(A,source_index,destination_index)
```

Are there any pre-defined functions that I can use in **maxima** to implement convergence or should I do loops with swapping and what constraints should I use? Assume that the size of the matrix is 3x3 with non-zero elements.

I already saw some related questions but the answers are in matlab.

Link: [Is there a function for checking whether a matrix is diagonally dominant (row dominance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553692/is-there-a-function-for-checking-whether-a-matrix-is-diagonally-dominant-row-do)

So, how can I do it in maxima?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that implements what you describe:

```
is_diag_dom_row (mat, i) :=
  is(2*abs(mat[i][i]) - lsum(abs(x), x, mat[i]) > 0)$

is_diag_dom (mat) :=
  every(lambda([i], is_diag_dom_row (mat, i)),
        makelist(i,i,length(mat)))$

swapped_matrix_rows (mat, i1, i2) :=
  makelist (
    mat[if is(i=i1) then i2 elseif is(i=i2) then i1 else i],
    i, makelist(i,i,length(mat)))$

row_swap (mat, i1, i2) := apply(matrix, swapped_matrix_rows(mat, i1, i2))$
```

To make it easier to write, I split both operations into logical pieces. Adding an extra copy of `mat[i][i]` means that one can sum over the list much more easily than trying to sum for i ≠ j. If you wanted to check diagonal dominance by column, it's probably easiest just to transpose and do it by row, since Maxima mostly thinks of matrices as a list of rows. (Although there is a `col` function to extract a column if you need it).

Comment: I should say: there's a slightly odd situation in Maxima where some things (like the `every` function) expect functions to map with, and some things (like `makelist`) expect an expression. I suspect this is to do with the tension between the Algol-inspired Macsyma language and the lispyness of the people writing the implementation. I guess you just have to check the docs (or try each way) until you've memorised which takes which.